Install python 3.12.3 in a docker image based on centos7
I am attempting to install python 3.12.3 in a docker image based on centos7. I've researched how to do this, and it seems there is no redhat prebuilt rpm to install, so my only choice is to build from source. Following instructions on the web, I created this
Dockerfile:
FROM centos:7

# Set bash as the default shell
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum install -y openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel zlib-devel gcc wget epel-release.noarch openssl11-devel
RUN yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools"
# RUN set -x \
#    localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 \
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.3/Python-3.12.3.tgz \
   && tar -xzf Python-3.12.3.tgz\
   && cd Python-3.12.3\
   &&  sed -i 's/PKG_CONFIG openssl /PKG_CONFIG openssl11 /g' configure\
   && ./configure --enable-optimizations \
   && make altinstall

Make runs for a while, and I even see a lot of unit tests pass. But ultimately, it is failing with this error:
#0 650.1        Programs/_bootstrap_python.o Modules/getpath.o -lpthread -ldl  -lutil                        -lm
#0 650.7 ./_bootstrap_python ./Programs/_freeze_module.py abc ./Lib/abc.py Python/frozen_modules/abc.h
#0 650.8 Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
#0 650.8 Python runtime state: initialized
#0 650.8 Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 650.8   File "/Python-3.12.3/Lib/site.py", line 73, in <module>
#0 650.8     import os
#0 650.8   File "/Python-3.12.3/Lib/os.py", line 29, in <module>
#0 650.8     from _collections_abc import _check_methods
#0 650.8 SystemError: <built-in function compile> returned NULL without setting an exception
#0 650.8 make[1]: *** [Python/frozen_modules/abc.h] Error 1
#0 650.8 make[1]: Leaving directory `/Python-3.12.3'
#0 650.8 make: *** [profile-opt] Error 2
------
Dockerfile:13
--------------------
  12 |     #    localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 \
  13 | >>> RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.3/Python-3.12.3.tgz \
  14 | >>>    && tar -xzf Python-3.12.3.tgz\
  15 | >>>    && cd Python-3.12.3\
  16 | >>>    &&  sed -i 's/PKG_CONFIG openssl /PKG_CONFIG openssl11 /g' configure\
  17 | >>>    && ./configure --enable-optimizations \
  18 | >>>    && make altinstall
  19 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -c wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.3/Python-3.12.3.tgz    && tar -xzf Python-3.12.3.tgz   && cd Python-3.12.3   &&  sed -i 's/PKG_CONFIG openssl /PKG_CONFIG openssl11 /g' configure   && ./configure --enable-optimizations    && make altinstall" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2

Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
Host OS : Ubuntu 18.04.1
Where have I gone wrong?

After a lot of experimentation, I was able to answer this question myself. The key pieces were getting devtoolset-10 installed along with openssl11 and properly referencing ssl11 from the configure utility.
Posting the solution here for anyone seeking the same. Here is the Dockerfile:
FROM centos:7

# Set bash as the default shell
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum install -y \
    gcc \
    bzip2-devel \
    libffi-devel \
    zlib-devel \
    libuuid-devel \
    libsqlite3x-devel \
    readline-devel \
    tk-devel \
    gdbm-devel \
    db4-devel \
    libpcap-devel \
    xz-devel \
    wget epel-release.noarch \
    centos-release-scl scl-utils
# Need to re-invoke yum after scl install
RUN yum install -y openssl11 openssl11-devel devtoolset-10 \
  && yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools" 
  
RUN source scl_source enable devtoolset-10 \
   && wget -q https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.3/Python-3.12.3.tgz \
   && tar -xzf Python-3.12.3.tgz\
   && mkdir /usr/local/openssl11 \
   && cd /usr/local/openssl11 \
   && ln -s /usr/lib64/openssl11 lib \
   && ln -s /usr/include/openssl11 include \
   && cd /Python-3.12.3\
   && export OPENSSL_LIBS=/usr/lib64/libssl.so \
   && ./configure \
   --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl11 \
   --with-openssl-rpath=/usr/lib64/openssl11 \
   --enable-optimizations
WORKDIR /Python-3.12.3
RUN source scl_source enable devtoolset-10 \
  && make altinstall \
  && cd / && rm -f Python-3.12.3.tgz \
  && rm -rf Python-3.12.3
  && yum -y groups remove "Development Tools"\
  && yum -y remove devtoolset-10 centos-release-scl scl-utils\
    bzip2-devel libffi-devel zlib-devel openssl11-devel \
    libuuid-devel \
    libsqlite3x-devel \
    readline-devel \
    tk-devel \
    gdbm-devel \
    db4-devel \
    libpcap-devel \
    xz-devel \
  && yum clean all\
  && rm -rf /var/cache/yum


Despite a lot of fiddling I couldn't get Python 3.12.3 to build, but here's a Dockerfile that installs Python 3.10.14 onto Centos 7.
For my understanding:

Would you consider a later version of Centos?
Is there specific functionality that you need in Python 3.12.3 or would another Python 3 version suffice?

FROM centos:7

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10.14

RUN yum -y update && \
    yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools" && \
    yum install -y \
        gcc \
        make \
        openssl-devel \
        bzip2-devel \
        libffi-devel \
        zlib-devel \
        wget \
        libuuid-devel \
        libsqlite3x-devel \
        readline-devel \
        tk-devel \
        gdbm-devel \
        db4-devel \
        libpcap-devel \
        xz-devel

WORKDIR /usr/src
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz && \
    tar -zxf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz

WORKDIR /usr/src/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}
RUN ./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --with-ensurepip=install &&
    make altinstall

RUN yum clean all && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum && \
    rm -rf /usr/src/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz

RUN ln -sf /usr/local/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python3 && \
    ln -sf /usr/local/bin/pip3.10 /usr/bin/pip3

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH


Thank you! I chose python 12 because it is the current stable release. I'm afraid I'm stuck with centos7 for a variety of reasons I won't go into.  3.10 would definitely be an improvement and last me until 2026 (at least).

Great. Then my solution should suffice!
